# Code running into redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess

Why is the following code running into redirect loop

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.16\.15\.17
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jgel/maintenance.php [R=307,L]
```

Resources is a folder

Comment: It's better to use `[R=503,L]`. See https://plus.google.com/115984868678744352358/posts/Gas8vjZ5fmB

Comment: @Gerben, +1 on 503 vs 307, but this doesn't explain the redirect loop

Comment: @TerryE you had already provided the answer, so I +1'ed that one.

Comment: Sorry +1's all round then.  Looks like we're in agreement ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `/jgel/maintenance.php` succeeds on Cond1, Cond2, Cond3 and the rule regexp.

Changing Cond2 to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance\.php$
```

would then cause it to fail on Cond2 and stop the rewrite loop, as would

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/jgel)?/maintenance\.php$
```